# Opposite side / other people

Tags: word-choice, phrase-request

How to mention other people in general explanations such as the following?

> You must be able to explain yourself to opposite side clearly.

Can I use "opposite side" and "other side/ people"?

Answer (score 1):

> You must be able to explain yourself to the other side clearly.
>
> You must be able to explain yourself to the opposite side clearly.

Both of these are all right; the first is slightly more natural-sounding.

> You must be able to explain yourself to other side clearly.
>
> You must be able to explain yourself to opposite side clearly.

Neither of these are acceptable English without the article 'the'.

Answer (score 0):

As what @rcook said, we need the articles.

Since the audience is other people, I suggest we use just the term straight, as in

'You must be able to explain yourself to the other people/ the rest of the people clearly.'

'Opposite side' and 'the other side' seem slightly unfriendly.

Comment: To clarify: Only use _the opposite side_ if you are talking about two groups of people expressing opposite views. It doesn't have to be an argument, it could be a friendly debate. If this isn't what you mean, just use _other people_.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you. That is a good point I feel but I could not bring up